# OfflineIMAP: Attempts to resync all emails if I define a reverse nametrans

Tags: offlineimap

I upgraded [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) to 6.5.4 from 6.3.4 so that it will automatically copy new folders to the remote, but I have a problem with folders that already exist locally and remotely.

Suppose `MyFolder` has 4 messages, both locally and remotely (it's already synced). Then OfflineIMAP will upload the 4 messages from local to remote, and then it will remove the 4 "old" messages from the remote. The result will be that `MyFolder` will be synced in the end, but with much unnecessary traffic - it was already synced in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

OfflineIMAP is currently in stable version 6.5.6.

I suggest upgrading to the latest release, or, if that doesn't work, to the latest
development version via its [github home](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/tree/next).

If the problem still exists, you should [report the problem](http://offlineimap.org/development.html#ref-reporting-bugs) to the developers.

Comment: Thanks. I followed this advice, resulting in this report: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.mail.imap.offlineimap.general/6520 (unfortunately the email archive system partly snips the debug log).